# Find a order 6 modulo 43

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Note that $$ A = \{ 1,\ 2,\ \cdots,\ 42\} $$

Let $ A_6 = \{ a\in A|\ a$ has order $6 \}$ (Note that $2=\phi(6) = |A_6| $)

To find $A_6$ we use the following fact : $ 3$ is a primitive root. Since $
3^{12}\equiv 1\ (43) $ so $ 3^2\in A_6$

But here note that $x^6-1=(x-1)(x^2+x+1)(x^3+1)$ So $$ 9^2 + 9 +1,\ 9^3+1 $$ are not 
multiple of $43$ so that $9$ is not in $A_6$

What am i wrong ?

Correction : Let $A_k =\{ a\in A|\ a$ has order $k\}$ so that $|A_k|=\phi(k)$

And $$ 42 = \sum_{k\ |\ 42}\phi(k),\ A=\bigcup_{k\ |\ 42}A_k$$

To answer the question, since $3$ is primitive so $$ A_6= \{ 3^7,\ 3^{35} \}$$

Comment: $3$ is a primitive root, hence $3^{42} \equiv 1 (43)$. Why do you say that $3^{12} \equiv 1 (43)$? In fact the result is $3^7 = 37 \ (43)$

Comment: I see. I will correct

Answer (score 1):

$\cdot \ \text{Here} <\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{NZ},+> \Rightarrow \text{Id} = 0$. $$(1) \ \gcd\{6,43\} = 1 \ ,\text{then} |6| = \text{lcm}(6,43) = 6(43) = 258$$.

$\textbf{Comment}$: I hope I didn't misread your question, but I used for $a \in G$ where $G$ is a group then we definr $|a| = \{\text{the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $a^n=e$ } \}$.